# Como hallo el cociente de una division en c++

Tags: dev-c++, division

solo conozco un metodo el cual es este

```
int a;
a=5/2;
//a=2
```

pero me preguntaba si hay uno mejor o si existe alguna funcion

Answer (score 1):

Las restas y multiplicaciones no son mas que sumas y restas, puedes obtener el resultado sumando y restando de la siguiente forma:

```
long dividir(long &num,long divisor){
int resultado=0;
while (num>=divisor)
{
num=num-divisor;
resultado++;
}
return resultado;
}
```

Comment: Para complementar tu respuesta podrías decir que haces uso del algoritmo de Euclides